# Jest tests running super slow in Docker

Tags: reactjs, docker, jestjs

Our test suite runs and a good enough speed in our local dev environments. But in docker it's super slow.

We tried [options provided on the official Jest documentation site](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/troubleshooting#tests-are-extremely-slow-on-docker-andor-continuous-integration-ci-server) but both the options - [runInBand](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli#--runinband) and maxWorkers do not help.

Local:

[image: Local]

Docker:

[image: Docker]

We use react-app-rewired to bootstrap our app and to run the tests, the following task is used:

```
"test": "react-app-rewired test a --ci --watchAll=false --runInBand --silent"
```

Docker image used: mhart/alpine-node:12

Any pointers?

Comment: Good lord, I thought I was going crazy...  Tests that take 1 minute natively are taking 30 mins in Docker and I just cannot figure out why.

Comment: Could be that it's relying on entropy in some way, which can be a bottleneck in container environments.

Answer (score 0):

It's known issue even from Jest framework:

> https://jestjs.io/docs/troubleshooting#tests-are-extremely-slow-on-docker-andor-continuous-integration-ci-server

- Based on the findings, one way to mitigate this issue and improve the speed by up to 50% is to run tests sequentially.

`jest --runInBand`

- Another alternative to expediting test execution time on Continuous Integration Servers such as Travis-CI is to set the max worker pool to ~4.

`jest --maxWorkers=4`

Comment: OP explicitly mentioned that both options didn't help

Comment: jest --runInBand helps, thanks a lot.

Answer (score -3):

Not sure what your tests are doing, but the first thing I always suspect in cases like this is DNS or other network operation timeouts.

You should get an idea of *which* tests are taking so long (out of the 81) and see what they are doing.

If you can post some more specifics, you can get some more help, but that's about all I can tell you from what you have posted.